How to connect 2 web pages in spring boot java?
I have created student registration system in eclipse using spring boot in which there is a main page in which we can add new student(student id,student name,course,and fee).
And there is also edit and delete option through which we can edit or delete students. On clicking on add new option it will take us to another web page where there are text fields to enter student name course  and fee and there is a save button on clicking on save button it saves the student in database. After saving student information if we open main page it start showing student information which we have added but problem is on clicking on add new button my browser is not taking me to the web page where I can add student information both the web pages main page and the page where we can add student information are opening seperately.
I have tried to resolve this issue using chatgpt but no success so far. I want that on clicking on add new option it takes us to the page where we can add new student.

You are describing the problem well. Now please share the relevant code snippets. For example the HTML code for the "clicking on add new option". Assuming you are using the Spring Boot MVC? Please share the controller class.

For basic information try with a tutorial first. For example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf

there ar e2 html file i have created under template folder one new.html





Create New Product





Create New Student





Student Name






          <div alight="left">



Course





Fee





Save 






and another one index.html









Spring Boot Crud System -Student Registation


Add new



<div class="col-sm-5" align = "center">
             <div class="panel-body" align = "center" >
             <table class="table">



Student ID
Student Name
Course
Fee
Edit
Delete




Student ID
StudentName
Course
Fee

Edit


Delete












Please don't share the code as a comment. It's unreadable. Add it to the question as a code block.

Im sorry. Some advice would be to make it a little bit more organized for steps to recreate problem.
From my understanding
1st Open main page
2nd Add student
3rd Go back to main page, see recently added student
4th When trying to add a new student, it opens up a new tab to add another student?

It should open new tab while trying to add new student but it is not opening new tab how to connect html pages in spring boot

What to do? So that on clicking on add new it redirects us to another web page

Handling links and redirections are handled in the frontend like adding functionalities to button on click and redirections to new webpages, no matter which ever backend tech you are using.
But if you want your backend endpoint to redirect to the next webpage then you can simply use redirect::path.
@RestController
class StudentController {
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String redirect() {
        /** any additional code **/
        return "redirect::add-new";
    }
}


Can you tell step by step in which file to go and what code do I need to change

You can first check the HTML files for redirection errors and then you can add this to your StudentController class which is handling the students routes.
